# PHP Sessions and Passing Session ID

Tags: php, session

I have an API where I am passing the session id back and forth between calls. I set up the session like so:

```
// start API session
session_name('apikey');
session_id($data['apikey']); // required to link session
session_start();
```

Although I named my session and am passing the session id via GET and POST using the name, PHP does not automatically resume that session. It always creates a new one unless I set the explicitly set the session id.

I found some old user comments on www.php.net that said unless the session id is the first parameter PHP won't set it automatically. This seems odd, but even when I call tried it still didn't work: `rest_services.php?apikey=sdr6d3subaofcav53cpf71j4v3&q=testing`

I have used PHP for years, but am a little confused on why I needed to explicitly set the session with `session_id()` when I am naming the session and passing it's key accordingly.

#### UPDATE

It seems I wasn't clear. My question is why is setting the session ID with `session_id()` required when I am passing the id, using the session name `apikey`, via `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Theoretically this is no different than PHP's `SID` when cookies are disabled. But for me it doesn't work unless I explicitly set the session ID. Why?

Comment: what is your question anyway? Why do you need to use session_id() or why it isn't working?

Comment: The latter - why is the call to `session_id` required when everything is named accordingly.

Comment: You set the id, then start the session, the session then uses that id. if there is no id present it creates a new one. Are you saying that this session id is not maintained once you navigate to another page?

Answer (score 1):

It's because newer versions of PHP has a default value of 1 for `session.use_only_cookies` which must be set to '0' in order to let PHP get the session ID from `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the session first.

Comment: Actually, start the session after naming it [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

I find `session_name()` to be more appropriate.  Mucking around with the ID can be problematic.